# Breaking a list into strings, not characters

Tags: python, list, hadoop

I have a `defaultdict` that looks like this:

```
"Some text" : ["Some date", "Some date", "Some Date"]
```

I am trying to access each individual value of each key like so:

```
for processedTweet, date in tweetsDict.iteritems():
    print date
    for d in date:
        print d
```

This works fine in a normal Python script. It prints the entire list first then in the for loop it prints each individual date.

But when I send this as part of a Map/Reduce job to Hadoop, it breaks the list into individual characters, not Strings, i.e.:

```
Some date
```

becomes

```
S
o
m
```

etc. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map/reduce job in hadoop is distributing your list values to the for-loop instead of passing the entire list.  By default, when python iterates over a string object each iteration returns the next character in the string.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix this? Or at least circumvent it?

Comment: I got it sorted. The problem was that Hadoop wasn't sorting the output between the Mapper and Reducer